# Method unit testing: "AttributeError for a module

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a unit test for each method of the program I am writing, starting off with creating the class then the constructor and I receive the error:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe'.

Here is the code I have for this unit test:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

class CompanySales:
    def __init__(self, CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CSV):
        with open(CSV):
            df = pd.dataframe(CSV)
        self._dataframe = df
    

if __name__=="__main__":
    Sales = CompanySales("ABC","3 River St. N.Y.,N.Y.", "CompanySalesData.csv")
    print(Sales)
    Sales.setName("Dallas Store")
    Sales.setAddr("2929 First St., Dallas,Tx.")
    print ("Company Name was changed to")
    print (Sales.getName())
    print ("Company Address was changed to")
    print (Sales.getAddr())
```

Comment: `.DataFrame`, not `.dataframe`.  Case is important.

Comment: That worked, but now I get "AttributeError: 'CompanySales' object has no attribute 'setName'"

Comment: The class definition of `CompanySales` indeed does not have any method named `setName`.  What were you expecting?